# How to set multi-field value in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have below mapping -

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                 "status": {
                      "type": "text",
                      "fields": {
                         "code": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                         }
                      }
               }    
            }   
        }    
    }
}
```

I want to set value for both status and code like -

> status - CRITICAL 
>  status.code - 10

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it that way. You need to use an `object` type instead of a multi-field

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {          
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "code": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you'll be able to set

```
status.name - CRITICAL 
status.code - 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Multifields are not meant for the above use case you mentioned. `Multifield` analyze same data in a different manner.
As per [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) :

> It is often useful to index the same field in different ways for different purposes. This is the purpose of multi-fields

You can use `object` type like this

```
     "statusObject": {
           "type": "object",
           "properties": {
              "status": {
                 "type": "text"
              },
              "code": {
                 "type": "long"
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Note that `long` needs to quoted.

Comment: Ohh. My bad. Thanks for catching. Edited it.

Comment: In our use case we have to set values for status as well as code e.g status - CRITICAL and code-10. Searching will happen on status and sorting will happen on code[We don't want alphabetical sort]. <br> In ES 1.7 we were able to do that with groovy script and with the mapping pasted in my question. <br> `if (ctx._source.attributes.status?.equals('CRITICAL')) {ctx._source['status.code'] = '10';}` .

Comment: In ES 1.7 we use to have transform field in mapping in which we can pass the above script and it will run during data ingestion. Above script was running in ES 1.7, we just want to replicate that behavior in ES 5.2

Comment: I guess your requirement is searching on `status` field and sorting on `code` field, that can be achieved through this as well.

Comment: We want to insert the value of code based on the value of status dynamically during ingestion of data. We were able to do it in ES 1.7 by passing that script in 'transform' field of mapping.

Comment: Are you facing any issues using scripts. I think your question should mention these things provided in comments above.

Comment: You can refer to my first query for complete details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43908332/elasticsearch-groovy-script-syntax-to-set-nested-fields-value